# EventLogFile for Change Set Operation

Tags: eventlogfile, event-monitoring

We want to log Events for all change set deployment. As per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_supportedeventtypes.htm) we can use [Change Set Operation Event Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_changesetoperation.htm) but there is no event in Event Monitor to log it.[image].
Right now EventLogFile object not giving any detail about changeset deployment. Is there a way to enable Change Set log in Event Monitor?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a dashboard for Change set in event monitoring, Event Type 'Change Set Operation' is not part of the Event Monitoring template app as mentioned [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_app_admin_wave_dashboards.htm&type=5) in configuration wizard.

You may check https://salesforce-elf.herokuapp.com for logs and select 'ChangeSetOperation' under Event Type.